# Application running indefinitely while using spring-integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I am using `spring-integration` to merge two files . But while merging the files, the application is running indefinitely. Below is my code to merge

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void mergeFiles() {
        for (String file : fileNamesList){
            try {
                sftpRemoteFileTemplate.execute((SessionCallbackWithoutResult<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>) session -> {
                    session.append(session.readRaw("path/to/input/"+file), "path/to/output/file3.txt");

                
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Could not send file per FTP: " + e);
            } finally {
                sftpRemoteFileTemplate.getSession().close();
                log.info("closing FTP session ");
            }
    }
            }
```

The `fileNamesList` got injected properly and the application is starting fine. I checked the output folder in sftp server and in `file3.txt` only content of first file is present. After the last line of logs given below, logs are not getting printed any further . Below are the logs of application

```
 Started Application in 2.874 seconds (JVM running for 3.994) 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,386 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Connecting to 192.168.1.32 port 22 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,410 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Connection established 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,418 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,418 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,418 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,473 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,625 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,630 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,630 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,631 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server:  
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server:  
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: none 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,632 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client: none 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,634 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client:  
2022-10-09 19:08:37,634 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client:  
2022-10-09 19:08:37,634 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,634 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,639 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,639 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,649 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,655 [main] INFO  o.s.i.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory: The authenticity of host '192.168.1.32' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 7c:6a:e8:bb:2d:1e:4a:88:4c:b1:98:07:c8:cb:4b:34.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting? 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,655 [main] WARN  com.jcraft.jsch: Permanently added '192.168.1.32' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,655 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,655 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,659 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,660 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,666 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,666 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,669 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,670 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Next authentication method: publickey 
2022-10-09 19:08:37,799 [main] INFO  com.jcraft.jsch: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Comment: Why logs are JSON? How do you run this application ? Are you sure there is nothing more in app to make it stuck?

Comment: As of now I am running the application locally. Two other apps also use the same key to connect to SFTP . But I stopped them. I have run the application multiple times. Every time , it is struck at the same step and I am getting the same logs.

Comment: The logs were in JSON because of some configuration settings in my app. I have updated the log format now

Comment: Thanks. Your logs talk only about connection and authentication. Nothing data exchange related. Maybe you can share with us a simple project to reproduce and play with?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try checking the logs from SFTP server(currently I have no access to its logs) and try to reproduce the same with my local sftp set up and if I have the same result , I will come back